# How to create Application Insights API Key for annotations using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create Application Insights API keys from ARM template. I need to have the API key for write annotations created during resource deployment to have release annotations working during application deployment from Azure Devops.

I've tried to find information on how to get this working, but I can only find examples on how to use PowerShell or Azure REST API to create the keys.

What I need to get working is to create the API keys using the ARM template.
I have tried numerous attempts with json similar to this without success;

```
 {
  "name": "[variables('applicationInsightsName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "[concat('Component ', variables('applicationInsightsName'))]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "applicationId": "[variables('applicationInsightsName')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "action",
      "type": "apikeys",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Azure Devops Release Annotations",
        "linkedWriteProperties": [
          "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationName')), '/annotations')]"
        ],
        "linkedReadProperties": []
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The best information I've found so far is  [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-azure-monitor-application-insights/suggestions/18404869-enable-arm-support-for-api-access-keys), but it isn't much help.

Is it possible to have the API keys created using ARM templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not possible, ARM Templates only mimic `PUT` requests, whereas the `Microsoft.Insights/Components/ApiKeys/Action` is a `POST` request.

Comment: Thank you. I struggled a lot to find a solution to this but couldn't find any using ARM templates. The next best thing is to use Power Shell in deployment pipeline to create/retrieve API keys to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an easy way. You are able to use outputs with reference **InstrumentationKey**. Then you able to use it everywhere: another resource, linked template or use outputs for the next steps by Azure DevOps.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[concat('stackoverflow-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().name))]"
        },
        "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "web"
        },
        "requestSource": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "IbizaAIExtension"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "apiVersion": "2014-08-01",
            "properties": {
                "ApplicationId": "[parameters('name')]",
                "Application_Type": "[parameters('type')]",
                "Flow_Type": "Redfield",
                "Request_Source": "[parameters('requestSource')]"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs":{
        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY":{
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('name')), '2014-08-01').InstrumentationKey]"
        }
    }
}
```

I used it many times.

Comment: The Instrumentation Key is enough to collect telemetry, but doesn't work for securing the requests when you want to use the real time filtering of the live metrics stream. I also need the API Key for this specific scenario (roll out of services using ARM with integrated telemetry API Keys).

Comment: Is there a way how to add the key to it also using ARM?